# what does windbg command "d esp" exactly do?

Tags: windbg

I know that windbg command "d esp" display the content that esp points. But, what range of it?
How does it get the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `d` command displays memory. If you don't enter a range the default is 128 bytes. Most of the `d` commands use a default of 128 bytes, but e.g. the `df` uses 64 bytes.

So `d esp` essentially means display 128 bytes of memory starting from the address held in `esp`.